# Blazor Server - CircuitHandler.OnConnectionDownAsync is called during navigation

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, blazor-server-side

I have "OnConnectionDownAsync" of "CircuitHandler" class in my Blazor server code. But this evenhandler is invoking during calls to "NavigationManager.NavigateTo()". Any where described about this behavior or am I doing something wrong here, which is causing this "OnConnectionDownAsync" calls during navigation? This behavior is causing the close of existing connection and opening a new connection during navigation, which I feel an overhead.

```
public class TrackingCircuitHandler : CircuitHandler
    {
        private HashSet<Circuit> circuits = new();

        public override Task OnConnectionUpAsync(Circuit circuit,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            circuits.Add(circuit);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }
```

> //This is calling during navigation and causing a new connection open****************

```
        public override Task OnConnectionDownAsync(Circuit circuit,
            CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            TimeSpan time = DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay;
            circuits.Remove(circuit);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public int ConnectedCircuits => circuits.Count;
    }
```

Comment: Could you share the full code snippet how you are calling this. Did you have a chance to check the trace log for the request?

Comment: @Md Farid Uddin Kiron
I have this HTML <button @onclick="GoToCounter">Click Here</button> and it's eventhandler private async void GoToCounter()
    {
         NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Counter", true);
    }. After the line "NavigationManager.NavigateTo("Counter", true);", it's invoking "OnCircuitClosedAsync(Circuit circuit, CancellationToken cancellationToken)" to close the connection and then opening again.
The simple source code is here https://1drv.ms/u/s!ArnWsPocPHeKha06aYIcKcXnBEpzBg?e=b54J4i

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is now resolved. I incidently noticed that I was routing to the page after login as below.

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/RequestForm",true);
```

Above code forces page reload from the server and so this flow is closing the existing socket connection.

I changed my code as below, which won't reload the page during navigation and the existing socket connection keeps.

```
NavigationManager.NavigateTo("/RequestForm");
```